# swift Value of type 'SKNode' has no member 'rotate'

Tags: swift, xcode, class, overriding

I created a class named Robber that extends SKNode and I added instance of that class to the game.
but when I want to call custom function on instance it says "Value of type 'SKNode' has no member 'rotate' "

why that doesn't works?

> my GameScene class:

```
enter code here

func addRobber(){
    lastRobber = false
    robber = Robber(x: Int(frame.width),y: Int(frame.height),h:Int(frame.height),so:sOp)
    self.addChild(robber as Robber)
}
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    addRobber()
}
[...]
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
      [...]
      for sprite in self.children{
            if( sprite is  Dots_Destroy.Robber)  {
                sprite.rotate()     //Value of type 'SKNode' has no member 'rotate'
            }
      }
}
```

> my Robber class

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import Foundation
class Robber:SKNode{
    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "wrog.png")
    let sprite2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "dzialowrog.png")
    let spriteNode = SKNode()
    let g = true
    var life = 2
    init(x:Int,y:Int,h:Int,so:SimpleOpponent){
        super.init()
        [...]
        self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        self.name = "rob"
        self.addChild(sprite)
        self.addChild(sprite2)
        self.position = so.sprite.position
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0x1 << 103
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0x1 << 104
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0x1 << 1


    }
    func rotate(){
        self.run(SKAction.rotate(byAngle: 3.15, duration: 0.3))

    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

is there a suggestion to fix the problem by Xcode? try it and see. Xcode is actually very helpful and solving issue by itself.

Click the red alert "i" icon that is showing on the line of the error, try any suggestions by Xcode or just click fix if possible.

Comment: I cat't do this here